# Scroll animation using React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add some animation on scroll using React JS. I have a navigation as follows :

```
render(){
  return (
       <ul className="noPadding">
           <li style={{paddingTop: 20}}> <Link to="" onClick={this.handleScroll.bind(this, refs.home)}>Home </Link></li>
           <li style={{paddingTop: 20}}> <Link to="" onClick={this.handleScroll.bind(this, refs.whyUs)}>Kenmerken </Link></li>
           <li style={{paddingTop: 20}}> <Link to="" onClick={this.handleScroll.bind(this, refs.benefits)}>Voordelen </Link></li>
           <li style={{paddingTop: 20}}> <Link to="" onClick={this.handleScroll.bind(this, refs.whoAreWe)}>Wie zijn wij?</Link></li>
           <li style={{paddingTop: 20}}> <Link to="" onClick={this.handleScroll.bind(this, refs.contact)}>Contact </Link></li>
       </ul>
  )
}
```

And handle scroll function is as follows :

```
 handleScroll(ref, event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let offset = this.props.offsets.offsets[ref];
    window.scrollTo(0, offset);
}
```

This works fine, when I click on the link I get to the section that I want.

But I would like to add some animation. I do **not** want to use `jquery`.

Any advice on how to do this?

Comment: try with `velocity.js` if not jquery as library else write custom code for the animation

Comment: https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll

Comment: @AatifBandey I would like to write custom code. I do not want to use an external component.